# Navigation menu is displayed under footer

Tags: menu, global-menu

There was Drupal update (7.67) and CiviCRM update (5.13.5), main navigation menu got lost and it is now in the footer...

[image]

I've already did cashe cleaning and menu rebuild. Nothing changed.
Did any one have similar problem?

Comment: Check if resource URL is correctly set under `Administer -> System Settings -> Resource URL` menu or `https://site-name/civicrm/admin/setting/url?reset=1` link.

Comment: everything is set up in accordance to documentation. There is no change in menu placement

Comment: I have the same issue with 5.14

Comment: Updating Directory and resource url and than clearing Drupal and CiviCRM cache solved my problem. Do check the variables are set correctly by clicking on ? in Directory and resource url forms.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but it's a multi-site and 4 out of 6 sites are fine, with just 2 with no menu. They also won't display the CiviCRM Status page. I've refreshed the Drupal and CiviCRM cache. No changes to resource URLs...